# how to fix "Missing return statement" in java

Tags: java, android

Im making a java method for an android app that returns the directory the app should be working in in the external directory.

I'm having a problem handling the returns and I don't know how to fix the error of "Missing return statement".

```
public String getpath() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        String extdir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File path = new File(extdir, "App");
        if(path.exists()) {
            return path.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        else {
            checkandmakepath();
            getpath();
        }
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Could not access External Directory!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent to_main = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(to_main);
        MainActivity.this.finish();
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to make sure all paths return something.

Comment: *"checkandmakepath();
            getpath();"* Please learn common [Java naming conventions](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/names.doc.html#73307) (specifically the case used for the names) for class, method & attribute names & use them consistently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public String getpath()
```

Implies that your method will return a `String` object, which is only done inside your if statements. Place this at the end of your method to ensure something is always returned no matter what conditions you go through. (You don't need to do this at the end of every else since you already return at the if branch.)

```
return null;
```

If you don't want to exit the method until a path is returned, you can do a `while` loop for it, but this may cause it to be infinite so this is best handled by whatever is calling your method instead.

Comment: Please look at the comment in the answer above you. Thanks!

Comment: @VaibhavAggarwal Edited. Looking at your code, what you want will probably cause an infinite loop. You should take a better look at your design to handle a situation where you can't get a value to return.

Answer (score 1):

A possible solution for your problem (there are more) return something where there are comments:

```
public String getpath() {
    String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
    if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
        String extdir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
        File path = new File(extdir, "App");
        if(path.exists()) {
            return path.getAbsolutePath();
        }
        else {
            checkandmakepath();
            return getpath(); // Return the recursive call's value
        }
    }
    else {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Could not access External Directory!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Intent to_main = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        startActivity(to_main);
        MainActivity.this.finish();
        // RETURN SOMETHING HERE (return ""; or the like)
        return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want the method to exit until it manages to return the path. If i add returns, will it still retry making the path till it exists?

Comment: Edited for it to call your method recursively

Answer (score 1):

add `return` statement in your both `else blocks`

Answer (score 1):

Every method in java which has a return type in its signature should return a value. In your code there are multiple execution paths due to the if/else statements. And you are doing the return only in one of the if statement. But in scenarios where that if is not executed, the flow will go to other else blocks and there is no return statement, which is causing the compiler to complain.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on what do you want. 
But I will do sth like below

```
public String getpath() {
String returnPath = null;
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    String extdir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    File path = new File(extdir, "App");
    if(path.exists()) {
        return path.getAbsolutePath();
    }
    else {
        checkandmakepath();
        returnPath = getpath();

    }
}
else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Could not access External Directory!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent to_main = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(to_main);
    MainActivity.this.finish();
}
return returnPath;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use another variable as a flag to check when to return String.

And I also think if the `Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)` return false, I think you should define some String to return other than `null`, to notify the state of the Enviroment.

`startActivity(to_main);` and `MainActivity.this.finish();` should be call only when the program receive the notify String.

Answer (score 0):

```
else {
  Toast.makeText(this, "Could not access External Directory!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  Intent to_main = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
  startActivity(to_main);
  MainActivity.this.finish();
}
```

in this block you are starting the MainActivity class and then destroying it it which doesn't make sense. Just check your logic here.

for return statement, you can do like this

```
public String getpath() {
String state = Environment.getExternalStorageState();
if(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED.equals(state)) {
    String extdir = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath();
    File path = new File(extdir, "App");
    if(path.exists()) {
        return path.getAbsolutePath();
    }
    else {
        checkandmakepath();
        return getpath();
    }
}
else {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Could not access External Directory!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    Intent to_main = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
    startActivity(to_main);
    MainActivity.this.finish();
    return null;
 }
}
```